# Additive non-abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, abelian-groups

Sometimes I see in books the term "additive Abelian groups". In my opinion, when we use addition to represent the group operation, we already have in mind that the operation is commutative. So additive group means Abelian group. Am I wrong? Are there "additive non-abelian groups"?

I quote this from a book:

"...it is shown that any additive group $M$ admits a scalar multiplication by integers, and if $M$ is Abelian, the properties are satisfied to make $M$ a $Z$-module ..."

Why the author needs to say "if $M$ is Abelian", given that it is said to be additive?

If the addition is not assumed to be Abelian, then it is a general binary operation, so the author was saying " ... it is shown that any group $M$ admits a scalar multiplication by integers and if $M$ is Abelian, the preperties are satisfied to make $M$ a $Z$-module ..."
Right?

Comment: The term "additive group" is really just kind of instructive - it encourages you to think of the binary operation as addition in some way. So yes, in general these groups will be abelian.

Comment: Per http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AdditiveGroup.html the additive notation is preferred for use with Abelian groups.

Comment: “Additive” refers to the notation used for the operation; it has nothing to do with abeliannes; it's a fact that *usually* (but not necessarily) addition is used for commutative operations.

Comment: @egreg, can you give an example of addition used for non-commutative operations?

Comment: @user139981 There are some generalizations of rings, where addition is not necessarily commutative, but the set is a group with respect to the operation. It's just notation; using $+$ instead of $\circ$ for denoting the operation on $S_4$ wouldn't make the group abelian.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, you could use any symbol to denote the binary operation.

Comment: You can denote the group operation by anything you want. So, could treat any group you know as an additive group. However, as you pointed out the additive notation makes us think abelian. It would be confusing and poor notation to use additive notation for a non-abelian group, but mathematically there is nothing wrong with making any group additive.

Comment: The symbol $+$ is used by lots of language to denote concatenation of strings or lists, and that operation is quite non-abelian.

Comment: so is it true that any group, abelian or not, admits a scalar multiplication by integers?

Comment: @user139981 Yes, typically denoted by $x^n$ in the general case.

Comment: @egreg I think your first comment should be an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In *additive abelian group* the word ‘additive’ refers to the symbol used for the operation $({+})$ and, in principle, it has nothing to do with the group being abelian. It's true that in most cases the additive notation is used for abelian groups (or, more generally, for commutative operations), but this is not universal.

For instance, the two operations on near-rings are usually denoted by addition and multiplication, but addition is not required to be commutative although a near-ring must be a group with respect to addition (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-ring).